# How to use the current Firebase "alias" name in an NPM script?

Tags: firebase, npm

I want to get the current Firebase project alias and use that in an NPM script.

When I run `firebase use` I get this terminal console output:

```
Active Project: agentcake (agentcakeapp-b514b)

Project aliases for /Users/BenJackGill/Dev/seoturbo/apps:

* default (agentcakeapp-b514b)
* agentcake (agentcakeapp-b514b)

Run firebase use --add to define a new project alias.
```

So I am trying to assign the dynamically generated "agentcake" part to a variable like `$FIREBASE_ALIAS` and use it in an NPM script. For example:

```JSON
"scripts": {
  "start": "FIREBASE_ALIAS=$(firebase use | grep -o 'Active Project:.*' | cut -d ' ' -f 3) && icongenie generate -i src/assets/$FIREBASE_ALIAS/square-transparent-1024px-icon.png && cross-env ALIAS=$FIREBASE_ALIAS quasar dev",
},
```

But that is outputting `$FIREBASE_ALIAS` as a literal string instead of using it as a variable that contains `agentcake`.

See here the output:

```
FIREBASE_ALIAS=$(firebase use | grep -o 'Active Project:.*' | cut -d ' ' -f 3) && icongenie generate -i src/assets/$FIREBASE_ALIAS/square-transparent-1024px-icon.png && cross-env ALIAS=$FIREBASE_ALIAS quasar dev
```

P.S. I am running this on MacOs (Ventura)